# AngularJS equivalent of jQuery .load()?

Tags: ajax, jquery, angularjs

What's the AngularJS way to do this?

```
$('#container').load('http://google.com');
```

**Note:** cross domain / external URL.

Comment: Angular or not, same origin policy won't let you load cross-domain HTML. That code won't work in jQuery either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the ng-include directive:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInclude

But, as Juhana pointed out, embedding cross-domain content won't work. (You might try using Cross-Origin Resource Sharing, I don't know if that will help in this case; and you'd need control over the other server anyway).